# iPhone NSTimeZone: localTimeZone confusion

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, objective-c, nstimezone

From what I understand, calling

```
NSLog(@"Local Time Zone %@",[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] name]);
```

gives you the local time zone of the device.  What it's giving me is **"US/Central"**, and I can't find that anywhere in the list of abbreviations in **[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]**, or the list of time zone names in **[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]**.  Where is this one coming from?  I need to pass the current device time zone to a Rails app, and it understands things like **"Australia/Sydney"** or **"America/Chicago"**, but not **"US/Central"**.

How do I take what localTimeZone is giving me and convert it to a string that Rails can understand (i.e. any time zone in knownTimeZoneNames, which is **supposed** to be all time zone names that the system knows about?)

Comment: What do you get for abbreviation:  [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] abbreviation]  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely using `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` without having required the `tzinfo` gem:

```
$ irb -rrubygems -ractivesupport -rtzinfo
>> Time.send(:get_zone, "US/Central").now
=> Tue, 17 Nov 2009 04:27:23 CST -06:00
```

If you don't require `tzinfo`, you'll only get a subset of timezones which is fairly useless.

***EDIT***: Just to avoid confusion, the reason I used the private `Time#get_zone` API is because that's what's being used behind the scenes when you call `Time#zone=`. If you don't require `tzinfo`, calling `Time.send(:get_zone, "US/Central")` returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Apparently I was just trying to solve the problem in the wrong place. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting that from within the simulator?
If so what does this command returns for if you run it from a terminal?
$ systemsetup -gettimezone

The timezone setting GUI in Mac OS 10.5 would set timezones to US/*.  If you manually set it from the console you can set it to one of the expected timezones.

Run this to get a list of the valid, and notice that US/Central isn't among them.
$ systemsetup -listtimezones

Run this to set it to America/Chicago
$ systemsetup -settimezone America/Chicago

Comment: I get US/Central from within the Simulator and when debugging on the device. 

When I run $ systemsetup -gettimezone, I get Time Zone: US/Central

If I change the time zone at the command line, does that affect the time zone on the iPhone?  Where is the US/Central coming from, if it isn't a valid time zone?