# Convert iOS localTimeZone to a knownTimeZone

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nstimezone

Using `NSTimeZone` the list of `knownTimeZoneNames` does not match the `timezone` retrieved by `localTimeZone`. How can I convert a timezone from `localTimeZone` to a time zone from `knownTimeZoneNames`. More specifically, the timezone `.name` return value must match a timezone in this list of timezones.

```
(lldb) po [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]
Local Time Zone (US/Pacific (PST) offset -28800)

(lldb) po [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] name]
US/Pacific

(lldb) po [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]
<__NSCFArray 0x10ab5c00>(
Africa/Abidjan,
Africa/Accra,
Africa/Addis_Ababa,
Africa/Algiers,
Africa/Asmara,
Africa/Bamako,
Africa/Bangui,
Africa/Banjul,
Africa/Bissau,
Africa/Blantyre,
Africa/Brazzaville,
Africa/Bujumbura,
Africa/Cairo,
Africa/Casablanca,
Africa/Ceuta,
Africa/Conakry,
Africa/Dakar,
Africa/Dar_es_Salaam,
Africa/Djibouti,
Africa/Douala,
Africa/El_Aaiun,
Africa/Freetown,
Africa/Gaborone,
Africa/Harare,
Africa/Johannesburg,
Africa/Juba,
Africa/Kampala,
Africa/Khartoum,
Africa/Kigali,
Africa/Kinshasa,
Africa/Lagos,
Africa/Libreville,
Africa/Lome,
Africa/Luanda,
Africa/Lubumbashi,
Africa/Lusaka,
Africa/Malabo,
Africa/Maputo,
Africa/Maseru,
Africa/Mbabane,
Africa/Mogadishu,
Africa/Monrovia,
Africa/Nairobi,
Africa/Ndjamena,
Africa/Niamey,
Africa/Nouakchott,
Africa/Ouagadougou,
Africa/Porto-Novo,
Africa/Sao_Tome,
Africa/Tripoli,
Africa/Tunis,
Africa/Windhoek,
America/Adak,
America/Anchorage,
America/Anguilla,
America/Antigua,
America/Araguaina,
America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires,
America/Argentina/Catamarca,
America/Argentina/Cordoba,
America/Argentina/Jujuy,
America/Argentina/La_Rioja,
America/Argentina/Mendoza,
America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos,
America/Argentina/Salta,
America/Argentina/San_Juan,
America/Argentina/San_Luis,
America/Argentina/Tucuman,
America/Argentina/Ushuaia,
America/Aruba,
America/Asuncion,
America/Atikokan,
America/Bahia,
America/Bahia_Banderas,
America/Barbados,
America/Belem,
America/Belize,
America/Blanc-Sablon,
America/Boa_Vista,
America/Bogota,
America/Boise,
America/Cambridge_Bay,
America/Campo_Grande,
America/Cancun,
America/Caracas,
America/Cayenne,
America/Cayman,
America/Chicago,
America/Chihuahua,
America/Costa_Rica,
America/Creston,
America/Cuiaba,
America/Curacao,
America/Danmarkshavn,
America/Dawson,
America/Dawson_Creek,
America/Denver,
America/Detroit,
America/Dominica,
America/Edmonton,
America/Eirunepe,
America/El_Salvador,
America/Fortaleza,
America/Glace_Bay,
America/Godthab,
America/Goose_Bay,
America/Grand_Turk,
America/Grenada,
America/Guadeloupe,
America/Guatemala,
America/Guayaquil,
America/Guyana,
America/Halifax,
America/Havana,
America/Hermosillo,
America/Indiana/Indianapolis,
America/Indiana/Knox,
America/Indiana/Marengo,
America/Indiana/Petersburg,
America/Indiana/Tell_City,
America/Indiana/Vevay,
America/Indiana/Vincennes,
America/Indiana/Winamac,
America/Inuvik,
America/Iqaluit,
America/Jamaica,
America/Juneau,
America/Kentucky/Louisville,
America/Kentucky/Monticello,
America/Kralendijk,
America/La_Paz,
America/Lima,
America/Los_Angeles,
America/Lower_Princes,
America/Maceio,
America/Managua,
America/Manaus,
America/Marigot,
America/Martinique,
America/Matamoros,
America/Mazatlan,
America/Menominee,
America/Merida,
America/Metlakatla,
America/Mexico_City,
America/Miquelon,
America/Moncton,
America/Monterrey,
America/Montevideo,
America/Montreal,
America/Montserrat,
America/Nassau,
America/New_York,
America/Nipigon,
America/Nome,
America/Noronha,
America/North_Dakota/Beulah,
America/North_Dakota/Center,
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem,
America/Ojinaga,
America/Panama,
America/Pangnirtung,
America/Paramaribo,
America/Phoenix,
America/Port-au-Prince,
America/Port_of_Spain,
America/Porto_Velho,
America/Puerto_Rico,
America/Rainy_River,
America/Rankin_Inlet,
America/Recife,
America/Regina,
America/Resolute,
America/Rio_Branco,
America/Santa_Isabel,
America/Santarem,
America/Santiago,
America/Santo_Domingo,
America/Sao_Paulo,
America/Scoresbysund,
America/Shiprock,
America/Sitka,
America/St_Barthelemy,
America/St_Johns,
America/St_Kitts,
America/St_Lucia,
America/St_Thomas,
America/St_Vincent,
America/Swift_Current,
America/Tegucigalpa,
America/Thule,
America/Thunder_Bay,
America/Tijuana,
America/Toronto,
America/Tortola,
America/Vancouver,
America/Whitehorse,
America/Winnipeg,
America/Yakutat,
America/Yellowknife,
Antarctica/Casey,
Antarctica/Davis,
Antarctica/DumontDUrville,
Antarctica/Macquarie,
Antarctica/Mawson,
Antarctica/McMurdo,
Antarctica/Palmer,
Antarctica/Rothera,
Antarctica/South_Pole,
Antarctica/Syowa,
Antarctica/Vostok,
Arctic/Longyearbyen,
Asia/Aden,
Asia/Almaty,
Asia/Amman,
Asia/Anadyr,
Asia/Aqtau,
Asia/Aqtobe,
Asia/Ashgabat,
Asia/Baghdad,
Asia/Bahrain,
Asia/Baku,
Asia/Bangkok,
Asia/Beirut,
Asia/Bishkek,
Asia/Brunei,
Asia/Choibalsan,
Asia/Chongqing,
Asia/Colombo,
Asia/Damascus,
Asia/Dhaka,
Asia/Dili,
Asia/Dubai,
Asia/Dushanbe,
Asia/Gaza,
Asia/Harbin,
Asia/Hebron,
Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh,
Asia/Hong_Kong,
Asia/Hovd,
Asia/Irkutsk,
Asia/Jakarta,
Asia/Jayapura,
Asia/Jerusalem,
Asia/Kabul,
Asia/Kamchatka,
Asia/Karachi,
Asia/Kashgar,
Asia/Kathmandu,
Asia/Katmandu,
Asia/Khandyga,
Asia/Kolkata,
Asia/Krasnoyarsk,
Asia/Kuala_Lumpur,
Asia/Kuching,
Asia/Kuwait,
Asia/Macau,
Asia/Magadan,
Asia/Makassar,
Asia/Manila,
Asia/Muscat,
Asia/Nicosia,
Asia/Novokuznetsk,
Asia/Novosibirsk,
Asia/Omsk,
Asia/Oral,
Asia/Phnom_Penh,
Asia/Pontianak,
Asia/Pyongyang,
Asia/Qatar,
Asia/Qyzylorda,
Asia/Rangoon,
Asia/Riyadh,
Asia/Sakhalin,
Asia/Samarkand,
Asia/Seoul,
Asia/Shanghai,
Asia/Singapore,
Asia/Taipei,
Asia/Tashkent,
Asia/Tbilisi,
Asia/Tehran,
Asia/Thimphu,
Asia/Tokyo,
Asia/Ulaanbaatar,
Asia/Urumqi,
Asia/Ust-Nera,
Asia/Vientiane,
Asia/Vladivostok,
Asia/Yakutsk,
Asia/Yekaterinburg,
Asia/Yerevan,
Atlantic/Azores,
Atlantic/Bermuda,
Atlantic/Canary,
Atlantic/Cape_Verde,
Atlantic/Faroe,
Atlantic/Madeira,
Atlantic/Reykjavik,
Atlantic/South_Georgia,
Atlantic/St_Helena,
Atlantic/Stanley,
Australia/Adelaide,
Australia/Brisbane,
Australia/Broken_Hill,
Australia/Currie,
Australia/Darwin,
Australia/Eucla,
Australia/Hobart,
Australia/Lindeman,
Australia/Lord_Howe,
Australia/Melbourne,
Australia/Perth,
Australia/Sydney,
Europe/Amsterdam,
Europe/Andorra,
Europe/Athens,
Europe/Belgrade,
Europe/Berlin,
Europe/Bratislava,
Europe/Brussels,
Europe/Bucharest,
Europe/Budapest,
Europe/Busingen,
Europe/Chisinau,
Europe/Copenhagen,
Europe/Dublin,
Europe/Gibraltar,
Europe/Guernsey,
Europe/Helsinki,
Europe/Isle_of_Man,
Europe/Istanbul,
Europe/Jersey,
Europe/Kaliningrad,
Europe/Kiev,
Europe/Lisbon,
Europe/Ljubljana,
Europe/London,
Europe/Luxembourg,
Europe/Madrid,
Europe/Malta,
Europe/Mariehamn,
Europe/Minsk,
Europe/Monaco,
Europe/Moscow,
Europe/Oslo,
Europe/Paris,
Europe/Podgorica,
Europe/Prague,
Europe/Riga,
Europe/Rome,
Europe/Samara,
Europe/San_Marino,
Europe/Sarajevo,
Europe/Simferopol,
Europe/Skopje,
Europe/Sofia,
Europe/Stockholm,
Europe/Tallinn,
Europe/Tirane,
Europe/Uzhgorod,
Europe/Vaduz,
Europe/Vatican,
Europe/Vienna,
Europe/Vilnius,
Europe/Volgograd,
Europe/Warsaw,
Europe/Zagreb,
Europe/Zaporozhye,
Europe/Zurich,
GMT,
Indian/Antananarivo,
Indian/Chagos,
Indian/Christmas,
Indian/Cocos,
Indian/Comoro,
Indian/Kerguelen,
Indian/Mahe,
Indian/Maldives,
Indian/Mauritius,
Indian/Mayotte,
Indian/Reunion,
Pacific/Apia,
Pacific/Auckland,
Pacific/Chatham,
Pacific/Chuuk,
Pacific/Easter,
Pacific/Efate,
Pacific/Enderbury,
Pacific/Fakaofo,
Pacific/Fiji,
Pacific/Funafuti,
Pacific/Galapagos,
Pacific/Gambier,
Pacific/Guadalcanal,
Pacific/Guam,
Pacific/Honolulu,
Pacific/Johnston,
Pacific/Kiritimati,
Pacific/Kosrae,
Pacific/Kwajalein,
Pacific/Majuro,
Pacific/Marquesas,
Pacific/Midway,
Pacific/Nauru,
Pacific/Niue,
Pacific/Norfolk,
Pacific/Noumea,
Pacific/Pago_Pago,
Pacific/Palau,
Pacific/Pitcairn,
Pacific/Pohnpei,
Pacific/Ponape,
Pacific/Port_Moresby,
Pacific/Rarotonga,
Pacific/Saipan,
Pacific/Tahiti,
Pacific/Tarawa,
Pacific/Tongatapu,
Pacific/Truk,
Pacific/Wake,
Pacific/Wallis
)
```

Comment: `po [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` prints the *description* of the timezone, not the *name*. Try `po [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] name]` - that should match a timezone of the list.

Comment: Nope, it does not. name returns "US/Pacific".

Comment: It would be interesting to dump the contents of abbreviationDictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `localTimeZone` is not included in the list is that your local time zone is showing an older name that's only supported for backward compatibility. The semi-official list of time zones is maintained by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). Their format is generally `Continent/City` but they support older names for compatibility.

Unlike API calls, older names are not in any sense deprecated. They're not current, but still completely valid.

If your local time zone is `US/Pacific`, the current official name for the zone is `America/Los_Angeles`, which does appear in the list. Based on your results it would appear that `knownTimeZoneNames` only lists current names. Why iOS is giving you an older name isn't something I can answer, but I do know that it's common.

To match them up, you have a couple of options:

- Run through known time zones and exhaustively compare the zone `data` attribute to find one that's equivalent. Yeah, ugly.
- Get the IANA data. It includes a file called `backward` that maps old names to new names. Include that file in your project. Then, if you get a zone name not found in the "known" list, consult the backward compatibility list to get the current name.

I wouldn't recommend @eipipuz's approach. It *seems* to work, but the problem with abbreviations is that they're not globally unique. Known abbreviations may vary depending on the user's locale (for example, more than one place as "EST" for its Eastern time zone). As a result some "common" abbreviations may have different definitions in different places, or simply have no definition.

Comment: Awesome well thought out answer, when I get the opportunity I'll test it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dictionary described in this question: [GMT timezone conversion in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871727/gmt-timezone-conversion-in-objective-c). Makes it pretty simple since you have the key.

Hold on a second, the problem is that you are going to have multiple entries that apply given only the code. What you have is not enough information.

This question is pretty close: [iPhone NSTimeZone: localTimeZone confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736699/iphone-nstimezone-localtimezone-confusion?rq=1) to your observation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Looks likes I'll try a back end solution as well. +1 but still doesn't necessary solve the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

```
NSString *known = @"US/Pacific"
NSString *abbr = [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:known] abbreviation];
NSString *expected = [[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary] objectForKey:abbr];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Timezone abbreviation is dependent on the current time. (In other words, it's not a one-to-one mapping.) Therefore, going to abbreviation and then back doesn't necessarily roundtrip.